# Can you export stl file from one object in one layer?

Tags: modeling, export

I had several pieces of a project in different layers.  After modifying a piece in layer e.g. 4, it was selected, active and in object mode.  I selected 'export', 'stl' and executed.  The file statisics show a very large file, and when I import the stl file, the entire project, from all layers, show up on one layer.
What did I do wrong?
TIA

Answer (score 8):

When exporting from *File > Export > STL* in the file browser tool shelf, in the bottom right tick the option *Selection Only*.

This will export you current selection though, I don't think there is a direct way to export current layer only, but you can easily select all visible objects if you turn off other layers so it should suffice.

You may need to be in object mode for this to work though

Comment: In Blenderv2.79, Selection Only option is at the left bottom.